# Add line break in script between comments (and code)

Tags: powershell, syntax, comments

This script doesn't work (there is something wrong with the backtick behind the commented line)

```
Get-PSDrive | Where-Object {$_.Free -gt 1} |
`
#comment 1 `
ForEach-Object {$c=0}`
`
#comment 2 `
{$c = $c + 1; Write-Host $c}
```

But this works

```
Get-PSDrive | Where-Object{$_.Free -gt 1} |
`
ForEach-Object {$c=0}`
`
{$c = $c + 1; Write-Host $c}
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: *What* are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to add comments on a multiline script (there is something wrong with the backtick behind the commented line)

Comment: The backtick is in a line comment. Characters in line comments are just literal characters.

Comment: You are piping to your comment. I don't believe that you're asking for is possible. You could put each command chunk into a variable. Then call all the command chunks as one. It's a little uglier. But can be more granularly commented I suppose.  You could try replacing `#comment 1` with `<#comment 1#>`

Comment: Actually, he shouldn't do what he's trying to do in the first place and move the comments to someplace more sensible.